# Blank screen after I press try Ubuntu without installing

Tags: installation, 13.10

I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.10. I get just a blank screen after I press **Try Ubuntu without installing**. I was thinking it would be an issue with nomodeset, but when I press **F6** on the screen with Other Options, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Istead of selecting anything, hit E to get the the startup script. On the 3rd or 4th line type:
"acpi _ osi=Linux acpi _ backlight=vendor" 
before "quiet splash". That should get you past the black screen and then it should freeze up again at a purple screen...
That's as far as I have come.
Good luck! I'll post here if I figure it out. (There's a chance I might just give up! haha)

Comment: Do I type "acpi _ osi=Linux acpi _ backlight=vendor", Hit Enter, then type "quiet splash"?

Comment: No. Right behind the "quiet splash" type the acpi command. then hit F10

Comment: The "quiet splash" command should be there already.